# get JSON Array from local server in android 6.0 with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get a JSON Array from this local server for five days:

```
localhost/match_picture/service.php?action=read
```

and i can't do it !!

I search it in google and read too many documentations !

here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class WebService {

    public static String readUrl(String server_url) {
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(server_url);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                        String json;
                        while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json+"\n");

                    }
                    return sb.toString();

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }
    }
```

and it's Main_Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Activity_main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<StructAcount> netAcount = new ArrayList<StructAcount>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String result= WebService.readUrl("http://localhast/match_picture/service.php?action=read");
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i=0; i<tasks.length(); i++) {
                    StructAcount acount= new StructAcount();
                    JSONObject object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
                    acount.id = object.getLong("user_id");
                    acount.name = object.getString("user_name");
                    acount.email = object.getString("user_email");

                    netAcount.add(acount);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (StructAcount acount: netAcount) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity_main.this, "username: " + acount.name + "\n" + "useremail: " + acount.email , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

it is runing on emulator and crashes in this line:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

and i dont know why ...

I am Searching for five days!!!!

I can do it with HttpClient
but i want to be update

I saw a vidoe in youtube that create a class in Main_Activity extends AsyncTask and make connenction in doInBackground(String... params). I try that and that works correcly. but because I want to do it in anoder class (WebService) and I dont know how can i sent result to Main_Activity , I remove that class extended from AsyncTask.

thank's for your help
sorry for my poor english

Comment: I would use Retrofit, a great library for such things! Having this said, I want you to know that your question lacks vital information, like *what* doesn't work.

Comment: Why arent you telling that your app crashes?

Comment: Why arent you telling where your app runs? Device or emulator? You cannot use 'localhost' to connect to a server on a pc.

Comment: What is happening? Show us your log.

You might want to consider using Volley framework. It's so easy!

Comment: Update your logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` to begin with.

And your app crashes.

Google how to solve it.

Comment: `AsyncTask and make connenction in doInBackground(String... params). I try that and that works correcly. but because I want to do it in anoder class (WebService) and I dont know how can i sent result to Main_Activity , I remove that class extended from AsyncTask.`. No good. You should use a thread or an async task. And you can have your code in another class and the async task in your activity. Or else use an interface or callback.

Comment: You can find plenty examples using an interface with an asynctask. Just spend some time googling and reading stackoverflow pages.